# SSL cert failing to load only using Firefox

Tags: firefox, iis, ssl

Yesterday I moved a site to a new IIS7.5 server from an old IIS7.5 server.

The site contains an SSL cert. I exported it from the old server and imported it fine into the new enviroment.

Safari,Chrome & IE load the https ok however firefox keeps give me an error

> Renegotiation is not allowed on this SSL socket.
>        (Error code: ssl_error_renegotiation_not_allowed)

What is wrong? why do all the other browsers work but not FF? I have stopped the site on the old server so I know its the new site been rendered.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suspect that it might have something to do with this: http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/120541. But I have no idea what exactly is misconfigured.

Answer (score -1):

This will happen if you have client authentication enabled for the website.
You need to click on the website -> SSL Settings -> Select Ignore under client authentication